# Finding the type of a variable in a macro in C++

Tags: c++, templates

Long story short: I need to find the type of a variable to use it in the `#if condition` macro. My `typeof()` in the provided sample is an imagined function, expression, code I would like to know. If even exists...
Otherwise, is there any workaround?

Sample code:

```
template <class T>
class MyClass
{
    T variable;

public:

#if typeof(T) == typeof(int)
    // compile section A
#elif typeof(T) == typeof(string)
    // compile section B
#endif 

};
```

Comment: Why aren't you using the actual functionality that templates provide instead? Using a macro cannot be the right approach

Comment: No you don't need macros for that, have a look at `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<int,T>)`. Just so you know macros are kind of a last resort kind of thing in C++ there is almost always a better (more typesafe) way.

Comment: In some cases you might also need to use template specialization, though without more context it's impossible to tell if this is such a case

Comment: Types don't exist when the preprocessor does its thing, so macros can't be aware of types.

Comment: I see... I figured a workaround... maybe? Could it be to check what the preprocessor would replace the T with. Is that a thing?

Comment: The preprocessor isn't involved in templates at all

Comment: In C++ you should stay as far away from macros as possible, as there's usually a C++ way to do it without that, like templates. What you need here is a specialization for `int` or `std::string`.

Comment: Remember that preprocessor substitution happens before the compilation phase begins.

Comment: Can't really do it wtih specialization for the types, because by some miracle, even `void` should be allowed to be used as T. Not in this example, I'm dealing with making a class that handles functions and their returns. Now, when the return type of the function happens to be void, building the project now results in failure, as there is no such thing as a `void variable`. Should I just ignore the issue and simply replace `void` with `bool` for example? With the macros, I wanted to exclude the part of the code that manages the returned values

Comment: template specialization is a thing, it was never necessary to emulate it via macros

Comment: `T` being `void` is not reason to not use specialization. If you encountered a problem with template specialization you should show the code for that

Comment: Okay then, I'll do the specialization... it appears to be working as intended, thanks for the workaround and thank you for pressing on this, despite my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to provide some members and/or member functions on some condition, a way is inherit from implement classes via [`std::conditional_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional):

```
struct MyClassIntImpl {
    void foo() {}
};
struct MyClassStringImpl {
    void bar() {}
};
struct MyClassDefaultImpl {};

template <class T>
class MyClass : public
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, int>, MyClassIntImpl,
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, std::string>, MyClassStringImpl,
    MyClassDefaultImpl>>
{
// ...
```

Where `MyClassDefaultImpl` is simply the default case, as needed for `std::conditional_t`.

Therefore a `MyClass<int>` object will have the `foo()` member function:

```
int main() {
    MyClass<int> u;
    u.foo();
}
```

---

This has some benefits over specialization:

- you don't need to copy & paste the same class for N types
- you can do checks like `std::is_integral_v`, which you can't easily do with specializations.